# Error message regarding IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I get this error message and I can't figure out why!

```
Error   1   'Exo5Chap12.ShortCollection<T>' does not implement interface member 
'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'. 
'Exo5Chap12.ShortCollection<T>.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement 
'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' because it does not have the matching 
return type of 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'.    
E:\MyFolders\Dev\c#\Chapter12\Exo5Chap12\Exo5Chap12\exo5.cs 9   18  Exo5Chap12
```

Here is the code with an implementation of GetEnumerator().
What is wrong?

```
 public class ShortCollection<T> : IList<T>
{
    protected Collection<T> innerCollection;
    protected int maxSize = 10;
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (innerCollection as IEnumerator<T>).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply don't cast the innerCollection object, for both the IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T> implementations.  See my full code in the posted answer below...

Comment: I notice that the error message tells you *exactly* what is going wrong here: that IEnumerable has not been implemented, that it is required to be implemented, and that the only method that could implement it has the wrong return type. That took quite a sophisticated error analysis already and yet it was not enough to allow you to diagnose the problem on your own. Would a different error message have been more helpful? What sort of error message would have enabled you to diagnose the problem without asking for help?

Comment: I am a newbie and am reading the Wrox (beginner) Visual C# book. I didn't know that I had to implement both IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T>, as it is not even mentioned in the book. Plus that code was the answer of the exercise (wondering whether they checked the code before printing out). I had a look at msdn website and wrox forum but they don't mention it either. I must say IEnumerable is quite hard for me to learn. But now that I read the error again I agree that makes sense.

Comment: I see -- so really the issue here is more about the weird design of IEnumerable<T> than the error message I suppose. IEnumerable<T> is weird because it has to be backwards compatible with pre-generics IEnumerable, and therefore there are two almost identical interfaces that are subtly different, which is a recipe for misunderstanding. Interfaces designed after generics were invented don't have this problem, fortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` are different interfaces and your code has to implement both. Your code only implements the GetEnumerator() of `IEnumerable<T>`, but not GetEnumerator() of `IEnumerable`. You should consider installing ReSharper which makes it easy to fix errors like this one.

Comment: Joel, thanks for the edit. Where do I find the documentation of formatting options?

Answer (score 12):

As others have said, you need to implement `IEnumerable` as well as `IEnumerable<T>`.  However, since `IEnumberable<T>` itself implemets `IEnumerable` this is trivial, just call your generic `GetEnumerator()`:

```
public class ShortCollection<T> : IList<T>
{
    protected Collection<T> innerCollection;
    protected int maxSize = 10;
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return innerCollection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
         return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that you have methods for actually adding and removing from the `innerCollection` and just left them out for brevity since they didn't relate to the question at hand.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes I left the rest out. Thanks again!

Comment: This is a much better answer than the one selected as correct, as it contains a code example. @Bon_chan consider changing your selection.

Comment: I spent an embarrassing amount of time trying to solve this. +1 for `IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement a few more things:

```
public class ShortCollection<T> : IList<T>
{
    protected Collection<T> innerCollection;
    protected int maxSize = 10;

    #region IList<T> Members

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return innerCollection.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        innerCollection.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        innerCollection.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return innerCollection[index];
        }
        set
        {
            innerCollection[index] = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICollection<T> Members

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        innerCollection.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        innerCollection.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return innerCollection.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        innerCollection.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return innerCollection.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return innerCollection.Remove(item);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<T> Members

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return innerCollection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return innerCollection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This code will compile...  :)